# Copy specific file to specific server using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I have 2 Files. File A and File B. Now after I create 2 Servers, I want to push File A to server1 only and File B to server2 only.

The solution I have below works well for 2 files. But its not very efficient when I have to scale out this model to more than 10 servers.

```
    - name: Copy file with owner and permissions
      copy:
        src: /srv/myfiles/serverA.file
        dest: /my/destination
      when: "serverA" in inventory_hostname
```

Can somebody point on how to accomplish below scenario more effectively using Ansible
File A to server A
File B to server B
File C to server C
File Z to server Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If your server names host1, host2, host3

In Control node your files are in /tmp
host1.txt
host2.txt
host3.txt

The playbook to copy the files to respective host's /tmp/ :

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - copy:
      src: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
      dest: /tmp/
    with_lines: ls /tmp
    when: inventory_hostname in item

Depending on the hostname and file name change the logic if required.
```